# Add a static code to an existent assembly

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, aop, reverse-engineering, patch

I have a very old assembly of our product' component, which can't be rebuilt.

It is built with .NET 4.0

To support TLS 1.1+ I need to execute 1 line of static code before execution of 1 of methods.

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

is there any option to do that with some AOP tool?

Comment: `inheritance` wont help you?

Comment: without recompilation

Comment: If the assembly isn't signed, you can try patching it with ReflexIL: http://reflexil.net/

Comment: That said, `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is static, so you should be able to put the line in the calling assembly

Comment: @KevinGosse what do you mean by this? anyway I have no access to calling assembly as well. there are lot's of cross-references..